# Change window title of Firefox browser after page has been completely loaded

Tags: javascript, caching, firefox

I am working on a project where i want to change the title of firefox window when it completes the page loading. For example i give URL www.google.com , now when this website is loaded i want to change the window title to e.g. "Page loaded".

I am using Firefox 20 for Linux. I have already tried following:

1- Took omni.ja file from firefox installation folder.

2- Unzip it using command:
     unzip omni.ja -d omni

3- Added following line in function onStateChange in file chrome/browser/content/browser/browser.js :
  window.name =  " Website loaded ";
 I am adding this line after following line in function:
  else if (aStateFlags & nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_STOP) {

4- Created omni.ja file again using command:
  zip -qr9XD omni.ja *

5- Replaced the original omni.ja file with the new omni.ja file.

6- Started firefox with --purgecaches command.

But still window title doesn't change when www.google.com has been completely loaded.

Does anyone has idea what i might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload=function(){
  changeTitle("New Title")
}

function changeTitle(newTitle){
    document.title=newTitle;

}
```